# Is it possible to mock Activator.GetObject()?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, remoting

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that uses a .net remoting object.

The remoting object is created by using Activator.GetObject(typeof(myRemotingObjectType), uri);

During runtime, the uri is server ip address of the remoting object.

Since I want to write a unit test, I don't want to initialize any .Net remoting to slowdown the test if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping it and have the wrapper implement an interface.  You can then swap the wrapper with a mock equivalent for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should wrap the Activator.GetObject() and pass it is as an interface?

Thanks for the suggestion.